# Word for an unpleasant need/necessity

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word which describes something that is not pleasant but is necessary. Moreover, there are no comparable alternatives for that.

Something like a *delightful pain*.

Comment: A necessary evil: something that you do not like but which you know must exist or happen.http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+necessary+evil

Comment: Perhaps consider *obligatory*. Not sure if it implies "without pleasure", but definitely necessity.

Comment: @Josh61, Seems interesting!

Comment: @Waterbagel, maybe, but I'm in doubt for that.

Comment: If your single-word tag/requirement isn’t binding and/or if by “not pleasant” you mean “unpleasant” (and not “not necessarily pleasant”), then the two-word, “necessary evil” suggested in Josh61’s comment is good, but otherwise, maybe you could reconsider  @Waterbagel 's  single-word adjective “obligatory” (or perhaps its noun “obligation”): “Whether we like it or not, paying our fair share of taxes is obligatory/an obligation.”

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172115/a-word-that-means-hateful-but-indispensable/172118#172118

Comment: And another: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204458/a-word-for-something-that-is-immoral-but-beneficial/204484#204484

Comment: @ermanen I wish the OP would include other examples, but I think this question is a little more nuanced. The title doesn't describe something that is *evil* or *hateful*, only possibly unpleasant. Same reason I don't think "necessary evil" is the right answer. The question may not have enough info to answer well, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Waterbagel: Thanks for the explanation but the nuance is not clear. It is still duplicate in my opinion. If people disagree, they can re-open. I can re-open also if OP explains why it is not a duplicate and give more details.

Comment: @ermanen Works for me! Hopefully they come back around.

Comment: Thanks to all, I think _necessary evil_ is the most appropriate one. As @Waterbagel pointed out, there is nothing hateful by its nature. Clearly, I mean a security mechanism that's powerful enough and there are no alternatives for that. However, it's not user-friendly and users usually face trouble with its interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, the title and post do not ask for the same thing.

A [necessary evil](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/necessary-evil) works for an unpleasant need [Cambridge]

> something unpleasant that must be accepted in order to achieve a particular result
>
> *Most Americans accept taxes as a necessary evil.*

A "delightful pain" (which, imo, isn't the same thing) is better expressed in the immortal words of Shakespeare:

> Parting is such a **sweet sorrow**.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parting+is+such+sweet+sorrow)

Single words like `taxes are obligatory/inescapable/unavoidable` don't really capture the 'not pleasant' part, because things can be obligatory without being particularly unpleasant.

Answer (score 2):

If you would consider a two-word phrase instead of a single word than maybe you could use:

**[bitter pill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pill)**:

> a bitter pill (to swallow)
>
> An unpleasant or painful necessity (to accept). (ODO)

---

Side note: I've checked an on-line [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bitter%20pill?s=t) for synonyms and it gave these:

> bad part;
>       bitter cup;
>       bummer;
>       downer;
>       downside;
>       wormwood

but I don't think any of these would work. *Bitter cup* in Google Books gives results either for coffee or tea, or for religious texts; *bummer*, *downer* and *wormwood* don't include necessity; *downside* and *bad part* cover only a bad aspect of an option.